# Meteor Blaze : dont wait for child template rendering before rendering parent

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, meteor-blaze

playing with Blaze i realized the following :
if i have a parent template where i include a child template with `{{> child_template }}`

then Blaze will wait for child template to be rendered before rendering parent. This can be good in some cases but not all.

For e.g if my parent template contains a `<h1>Welcome to my page</h1>` and child a list of 10 000 items. I would like a way to display `<h1>` asap and wait for the 10 000 items to appear later

what i'm doing currently to manage that is the following :

```
Template.parent.onRendered(function(){
    Blaze.render(Template.child, document.body);
});
```

it is working but i wonder if anyone have a better solution for this problem that seems pretty common. thanks

Comment: You could pass a custom boolean `canRender` argument to the child component that's `false` by default, but the parent component's `onRendered` sets it `true`. And the child component should check this argument and not render anything unless it's `true`.

Comment: @aedm That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @aedm thanks this actually seems to be a common architecture from what i've understood

Comment: @aedm care to post your comment as a reply so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a custom boolean argument to the child component that's `false` by default, but the parent component's onRendered sets it true. And the child component should check this argument and not render anything unless it's `true`.

```js
Template.parent.onCreated(function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict();
  this.state.setDefault({
    "canRender": false,
  });
}

Template.parent.onRendered(function() {
  this.state.set("canRender", true);
}

Template.parent.helpers({
  canRender() {
    return Template.instance().state.get("canRender");
  }
});
```

Pass the state to the child component:

```html
<template name="parent">
  {{>child canRender=canRender}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  {{#if canRender}}
    <p>Millions of items go here.</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, your Child Template has a list of 10000 items. so, this means you have subscribed to some collection. You can us below code to solve your issue.

```
<template name="Parent">
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
    </div>
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{> Child}}
  {{else}}
  <p>Loading Child Items...</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: actually the list of 10 000 items can be from a subscription OR not. but thanks